# AS2 check if string contains letters in specific order

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make in Action Script 2 a code that will check if a string contains a certain characters. 
For example:
String 1 - "wqeeqwe**j**qwqwq**a**retrt**v**iyiiyi**a**";
Obiously, The hidden word in here is **java**. I'm trying to make a code that will do like it:
If string contains letters "j,a,v,a" in order so do ------

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the AS2 syntax but something like this should work:

```
function containsWord(originalString:String, word:String):Boolean
{
    var lettersFound:Number = 0;

    for(i=0; i<myString.length; i++)
    {
        // check next letter in the originalString
        var currentLetter:String = originalString.charAt(i);

        // increase the lettersFound if the currentLetter is the next letter in our word. This also means that next time we will check for the next letter in the word
        if (currentLetter == word.charAt(lettersFound))
        {
            lettersFound++;
        }
    }

    // return true if the lettersFound equals the length of our word (meaning we've found all letters)
    return lettersFound == word.length;
}

var stringContainsWord:Boolean = containsWord("wqeeqwejqwqwqaretrtviyiiyia", "java");
trace(stringContainsWord);
```